# How to use inbuilt icons and template?

Tags: android, layout, themes, system

I'm trying to make a list that looks exactly like Sound setting in 2.3.4 as in this screenshot: [image: example]

1. The problem is that I tried using TableRow and ended up like this:

   ```
   ------------------------------------------
   Vibration                                >
   ------------------------------------------
   Only when not in Silent Mode
   ------------------------------------------
   ```

   instead of one large row as in the screenshot. What did I do wrong?
2. These inbuilt icons are nice (such as the ">" icon) - couldn't find on Google Image so I guess these icons are "inbuilt" in the Android OS. Is there any document we can refer about this? I'd like to use system text colours/background colours and these icons but don't know how to implement in the code.

Comment: i think you took two separate rows one for "vibration" and the other for "only when not in silent mode" that is the reason you came up like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is Listview but it is customizable you have to make xml file which display this tow Textview and icon(in your words).

> These inbuilt icons are nice (such as the ">" icon) - couldn't find on Google Image so I guess these icons are "inbuilt"

This is not a inbuilt icons but this is just image that set customarily.

Here are some links:

1. [Official Developer Community](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)
2. [fentastic Sai geetha blog](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)
3. [josecgomez.com](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/)

Comment: Thank you for these helpful links. It's a little bit complicated for the purpose above but sooner or later I'll need to get to it :)

Comment: after further investigation, I couldn't use PreferenceActivity because I have one entry on the screen that needs to pop up and asks for multiple-checkbox selection. (There is ListPreference but it is radio selection so not what I wanted). 

Hence the only way is to fully make a customizable view with customizable icons/fonts/colours.

Answer (score 4):

This is a PreferenceActivity.

[This link](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html) is good example of android preference. Using preference you don't need to make table layout and using detail button icon. Using preference this icon comes automatically.

The examples from [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/preferences.html) and [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html) may help you.

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for, will give it a try now!! Thank you very much.