# Android spinner problem

Tags: android, spinner

I've create the android application program..I have done the program that extends list activity. Is spinner works insdie the listview..pls tell some idea..Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot understand what you need, could you try rephrasing your question?

Comment: @uthra you want to use spinner into listview or spinner with the listview. if spinner into listview that means its like list of spinner like checkbox list.

Comment: please provide your layout xml file here

Comment: Please Provide Some Code & Description About Your Problem.

Comment: i want to use spinner into listview

Comment: I have attached my xml file..http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=U2Bvmq9r

Comment: i got you problem, just concentration on keyword :: you need to implement custom list-view in which each list-item has spinner are show right? so you need to implement with custom adapter.  i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411228/android-how-to-use-inbuilt-icons-and-template/7411283#7411283

Comment: and for next time you need to improve you asking question technique

Comment: @nik Thank you very much.Hereafter i improve to ask question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got you problem, just concentration on keyword :: you need to implement custom list-view in which each list-item has spinner are show right? so you need to implement with custom adapter.  i think this will help you [How to use inbuilt icons and template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411228/android-how-to-use-inbuilt-icons-and-template/7411283#7411283)