# Can i add components like spinner etc. in my listview with my listitems?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-listview

I am using a listview with n number of listitems. 
I have need to add a spinner with all my listitems. 
Is there any option to add the spinner dynamically.
Because i can't determine the number of listitems.

Comment: this person has same requirement of as your  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411228/android-how-to-use-inbuilt-icons-and-template/7411283#7411283

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, for this you need to create a custom list adapters. See this tutorial for more information

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Customize row.xml to add Spinner there as per your layout.