# How to place a ListView inside another ListView....?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need to place one list which contains headings and respective lists,

I have done it with two adapters, but i am not getting the output that i want...!

The list inside the list is not showing all the elements but only two.

How to solve this.....?

here is the screen shot.

[image: my screen]

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Why don't you use [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: use custome listview fundamental :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411228/android-how-to-use-inbuilt-icons-and-template/7411283#7411283

Comment: What about scrolling in such combination?
ListView in ScrollView is not recommended due to scrolling, it may be same with ListView in ListView.

Comment: i dont want to scroll the inner list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem...

1.place inner list view in a relative layout.

2.change its height based on number on items.

```
myRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ((ArrayList<Object>) myList.get(position)).size()*28));

//where 28 is the height of each item in the list.
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

> i dont want to scroll the inner list view

Then it should not be a `ListView`. Either use `ExpandableListView` for the whole list, or use a vertical `LinearLayout` for the "inside the list" contents (e.g., Chicken3, Matton3).

Comment: those items will chage dynamically... so i can't define in linear layout. i have to go for a list view.

Comment: @Noby: "those items will chage dynamically... so i can't define in linear layout" -- sure, you can. Read the documentation for `LinearLayout`, and its parent class `ViewGroup`, and you will find `addView()` and `removeView()`.